# Call external Api on button click and then render a child component with the api result data

Tags: reactjs, redux

```js
<!--Weather.js-->

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
import React from 'react'

import MyApi from '../api/MyApi';
import InputCity from './InputCity'
import WeatherData from './WeatherData'

export default class Weather extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            weather:[],
            city: ''
        }
    }

    makeRequest = (city) => {
        MyApi.getWeather(city)
            .then(function (res) {
                this.setState(function () {
                    return{
                        weather:res
                    }
                })
            }.bind(this));
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.makeRequest(this.state.city)
    }

    setCity = (mycity) =>{
        this.setState(function () {
            return{
                city:mycity
            }
        })
    }

    render(){
        const showWeatherData = this.state.weather;
        return(
            <div>

                <InputCity setCity={this.setCity}/>
                {showWeatherData && <WeatherData city={this.state.city}/>}
                {console.log(this.state.weather)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have three components:

- Weather

  - InputText
  - WeatherData

Now the InputText Component is rendered when the main Weather component is rendered, the InputText component contains a textfield and a button.
So now when i click the button need to call an openweathermap api and then display the result in WeatherData Component.
The WeatherData component must be rendered only after the button click.
How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

add some state to the Weather component, call it `showWeatherData` for example, set it to `null` in the beginning. Give it a value after you receive back the data from your api.

in your JSX inside Weather component, use the `&&` to short circuit the WeatherData component (just a short way instead of using an `if` or a tertiary operator)

```
render(){
  <InputText />
  { ShowWeatherData && <WeatherData /> }
}
```

Comment: But where should my API be called in the weather component or the weatherData component

Comment: you can call your api in the componentDidMount lifecycle method of the Weather component. I'd keep the two child components as presentational components, only pass the data to them as props.
Check these links for more info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: But my API needs an input from the text field in the inputtext component so that would not work I guess

Comment: pass the text from the textInput to the parent component, Check this example it's very useful: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up